# cant find variable props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to show the detail view when user taps on one of the list item. When the user taps on the listitem, I get an error saying Undefined is not an object
evaluating 'this.props.services.ser. Below is the screen shot of the error:

[image]

My list item page code is below:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ListView } from 'react-native';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducers from '../reducers/ServiceReducer';
import ServiceItem from './ServiceItem';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import ServiceDetail from './ServiceDetail';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 353,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingLeft: 20,
  },
});


const store = createStore(reducers);

class AutoCompActivity extends Component {


  renderInitialView() {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
    });
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.services);

    if (this.props.detailView === true) {
      return (
        <ServiceDetail />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <ListView 
          enableEmptySections={true}
          dataSource={this.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => 
            <ServiceItem services={rowData} />
          }
        />
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderInitialView()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { 

    services: state.services,
    detailView: state.detailView,
  };
};
const ConnectedAutoCompActivity = connect(mapStateToProps)(AutoCompActivity);


const app1 = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedAutoCompActivity />
  </Provider>
)

export default app1;
```

Each item that I display to the user is defined in js class serviceItem.js. Below is the code for serviceItem.js. I put the entire code inside TouchableWithoutFeedback. This is when I am getting an error when user taps on one  of the listItem. I looked at this code several times, but could not figure out where I am doing wrong

```
  import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image,  TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTheme } from 'react-native-material-kit';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import * as actions from '../actions';

const theme = getTheme();

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  title: {
      top: 20,
      left: 80,
      fontSize: 24,
  },
  image: {
      height: 100,
  },
  action: {
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      color: 'white',
  },
  icon: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 15,
      left: 0,
      color: 'white',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
  },
});

const ServiceItem = (props) => {
    return (

        <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
        onPress={() => props.selectServices(props.services)}
    >
        <View style={[theme.cardStyle, styles.card]}>

            <Text >{props.services.ser} </Text>

        </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
};


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { 
        selectServices: state.selectServices,
        services: state.services
     };
  };



export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ServiceItem);
```

When the user taps on each listitem. I am calling the class ServiceDetail.js. Below is the code for serviceDetail.js class:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Linking } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTheme } from 'react-native-material-kit';
import EvilIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import SimpleIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';
import * as actions from '../actions';

const theme = getTheme();

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
    borderColor: 'lightgrey',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
  },
  title1: {
      top: 10,
      left: 80,
      fontSize: 24,
  },
  title2: {
      top: 35,
      left: 82,
      fontSize: 18,
  },
  image: {
      flex: 0,
      height: 100,
      width: 333,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
  },
  closeIcon: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 5,
      left: 295,
      color: 'rgba(233,166,154,0.8)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
  },  
  icon: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 15,
      left: 0,
      color: 'white',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
  },
  textArea: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      paddingLeft: 20,
      paddingTop: 10,
      width: 260,
  },
  textIcons: {
      color: '#26a69a',
  },
  actionArea: {
      paddingTop: 10,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
      alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
class ServiceDetail extends Component {
    handleClick = (link) => {
        Linking.canOpenURL(link).then(suppported => {
            if (supported) {
                Linking.openURL(link);
            } else {
                console.log('Don\'t know how to open URI: ' + link);
            }
        });
    };
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <View style={[theme.cardStyle, styles.card]}>
        <Image 
            source={require('../images/background.jpg')}
            style={[theme.cardImageStyle, styles.image]}
        />
        <EvilIcon name={'user'} size={100} style={styles.icon}/>
        <SimpleIcon name={'close'} size={30} style={styles.closeIcon}
            onPress={() => this.props.noneSelected()} />
        <Text style={[theme.cardTitleStyle, styles.title1]}>{this.props.services.ser}</Text>

        <Text style={[theme.cardTitleStyle, styles.title2]}>from {this.props.services.Location}</Text>
        <Text style={[theme.cardTitleStyle, styles.title2]}>from {this.props.services.SecondLoc}</Text>
        <View style={styles.textArea}>
           <MaterialIcon name={'phone'} size={40} style={styles.textIcons}/>
           <Text style={theme.cardContentStyle}>{this.props.services.Phone}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.textArea}>
           <MaterialIcon name={'email'} size={40} style={styles.textIcons}/>
           <Text style={theme.cardContentStyle}>{this.props.services.email}</Text>
        </View>


        <View style={styles.actionArea}>
            <Text>Call</Text>

            <Text>Email</Text>
        </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { 
      service: state.serviceSelected,
   };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ServiceDetail);
```

My index.js class has the following code under actions folder:

```
export const selectServices = (serviceId) => {
    return {
        type: 'SELECTED_SERVICE',
        payload: serviceId,
    };
};

export const noneSelected = () => {
    return {
        type: 'NONE_SELECTED',
    };
};
```

My serviceReducer has the following code:

```
   import services from './services.json';

const initialState = {
    services,
    detailView: false,
    serviceSelected: null,
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SELECTED_SERVICE':
            return {
                ...state,
                detailView: true,
                serviceSelected: action.payload
            }

        case 'NONE_SELECTED':
            return {
                ...state,
                detailView: false,
                serviceSelected: null,
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I am developing this application on windows machine on android emulator. I know I am missing something. I looked at each and every line, but could not figure out what am I doing wrong. I am new to react native and trying to follow the example to make this app. I tried to debug the application using chrome, but keep getting an error that could not connect to remote debugging.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you pass props and use it to your `const ServiceItem`. You need to use `mapStateToProps` also then pass to your `connect` at `serviceItem.js`.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { 
      selectServices: state.selectServices,
      services: state.services
   };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ServiceItem);
```

Your ServiceDetail.js also should be:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { 
      services: state.services
   };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ServiceDetail);
```

Comment: I made the  above suggested changes and I started getting another error. I posted the screen shot of that error.

Comment: Thanks. I can see my ServiceDetails page, but my service items totally disappeared. If I click on the blank page, it goes to the servicedetails page, but I cannot see a single lisItem. I thought it is stylesheet issue and I removed all the style sheets, but still cannot see a service item

Answer (score 0):

Your ServiceItem component is just a presentational component, in my opinion, it need not to be connected to redux store, instead, pass the data and event hook from parent to ServiceItem component  and that will work just fine. That will solve your props problem as well.

Point made by "DennisFrea" still holds good. i am just suggesting another of achieving the same thing.